# vb.net how can zoom image

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a Custom Control for viewing images with zooming facility but without scrollBar, and its working condition is good. Actually The Custom Control is a **Panel with a Picutrbox on it**. I also using a TrackBar for zooming in/out the image. It is also working better.

But I am not fully satisfied, even it is covering the purpose of my App because I need **zooming PictureBox based on center point**. Now it is anchoring Top Left.

Another One is when Zooming out the image, the image goes to zero size at TrackBar's Zero. Even I limited zoom level to the panel size and working good, my unsatisfaction taking place here  also, as it is not responding at zero level of TrackBar. Here I need, the **original size of image** loaded in picture box have to go for **100% of TrackBar** and when image reached at **Custom controle size** have to go for **0% of TrackBar**. Then I will fullfilled.

I figuring my code here.........

**My Custom Control is a User Control Inheriting from Panel.**

***code for cutom control :***

```
Public Class ImageViewer
Inherits Panel

Dim AutoScaleDimensions As SizeF
Dim AutoScaleMode As AutoScaleMode

Protected Overrides Sub DefWndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    If m.Msg <> 131 Then
        MyBase.DefWndProc(m)
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

**On Form1**, I Placed my Custom Control- **ImageViewer1** and also placed **PicutreBox1 *with in* ImageViewer1**, Palced **Button1 and TrackBar1 on Form1**

**Changed Properties as follows**
ImageViewer1 - AutoScroll=True
PicutreBox1 - SizeMode=Zoom
TrackBar1- Maximum=100

**My Declared Variables are**

```
Dim imgName As String
Private SliderCenter As Integer = 50
Private originalImg As Bitmap
```

***Code for*    Button1.Click**

```
    Try
        Dim inputImg As FileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()

        inputImg.Filter = "Image File (*.Jpg;*.Bmp;*.Png;*.Gif;*.Tiff;*.Tif;*.PDF)|*.Jpg;*.Bmp;*.Png;*.Gif;*.Tiff;*.Tif;*.PDF"

        If inputImg.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then

            imgName = inputImg.FileName
            originalImg = New Bitmap(inputImg.FileName)
            Dim newImg As New Bitmap(imgName)
            PictureBox1.Image = DirectCast(newImg, Image)

        End If
        inputImg = Nothing
    Catch ae As System.ArgumentException
        imgName = ""

        MessageBox.Show(ae.Message.ToString)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try
```

***Code for*    TrackBar1.ValueChanged**

```
If originalImg IsNot Nothing Then
        If TrackBar1.Value > 0 Then
            Dim scale As Double = TrackBar1.Value
            Dim height As Integer = Convert.ToInt32((scale / SliderCenter) * originalImg.Height)
            Dim width As Integer = Convert.ToInt32((scale / SliderCenter) * originalImg.Width)
            PictureBox1.Size = New Size(width, height)
            If PictureBox1.Width <= ImageViewer1.Width Then
                PictureBox1.Size = New Size(PictureBox1.Width + (ImageViewer1.Width - PictureBox1.Width), ImageViewer1.Height)
            End If
            If PictureBox1.Height <= ImageViewer1.Height Then
                PictureBox1.Size = New Size(ImageViewer1.Width, PictureBox1.Height + (ImageViewer1.Height - PictureBox1.Height))
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

Please help me in your kind ........ Thank You.

Comment: your question is unclear . and if i try your code it does not work like you say.

Comment: Now i hope u can reach my question, testing my Code.